# Overriding the UL Bullets Styling For One Specific List

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website where the default CSS specifies:

```
    ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

This is necessary to keep the navigation bar clean (which is coded as an unordered list, basically) ...

Now, in the body of text on a particular page, I want to add a standard unordered list. So in a separate CSS sheet that exists for customizations, I added:

```
    ul.about-page {
        list-style-type: circle;
    }
```

And then on the page where I want the unordered list, I added this to the HTML:

```
    <ul class="about-page">
       <li>Some text</li>
    </ul>
```

I also tried some variations of the above, but in all cases it wasn't working. Instead no bullets were showing up (though the text was indented as expected).

Note: the most complicated thing I tried was to add the following to the custom stylesheet:

```
    ul.about-page li::before {
      content: "\25E6";
      color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1em;
      margin-left: -0.9em;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
```

And then on the page where I want the unordered list, I entered this HTML:

```
    <ul class=“about-page”>
    <li>Some text</li>
    </ul>
```

I was hoping that this — or some similar version of it — would work. But it also does not.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but after spending at least an hour searching online and trying various things, I can't seem to figure it out.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: You want to "-" sign before listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use class it is have More priority but when you use Address Model Selector like `ul li` it has more than priority of class then you must use this code

```css
 ul li {
          list-style: none;
        }
 ul.about-page li {
        list-style-type: circle;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
</ul>

<ul class="about-page">
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
</ul>
```